# Running oozie job gives IO Error E0803

Tags: oozie, bigtop

On running a job on Oozie , using the command

```
    oozie job 
       -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie 
       -config /usr/share/doc/oozie/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties 
       -run
```

I get the error :

```
    Error: E0803 : E0803: IO error, The transaction has been rolled back.  
    See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
```

Installation is done from bigtop-0.6.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Try to upgrade your Oozie.
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_17_4.html